# Facebook Requests Dialog on Mobile failed

Tags: facebook, mobile, dialog, touch

Here is my source code:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', to: fbId, message: "hello"}, function(resp){
   if(resp.request_ids){
      $('#req-id').val(resp.request_ids);
        $('form').submit();
   } else {
       return false;
   }
});
```

And here is what I get when I run it in a browser with User Agent set to iPhone:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
```

It also popup a window to display the message which is not wanted. I've tried to add "display:touch" parameter without any fortune.

Did anyone encountered this before?

Thanks,
Green

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook Requests dialog is not available on mobile at this time. We are working on a mobile version. Please follow our blog to stay updated on when this launches.

Comment: This was working for me for a while and suddenly stopped working (this was after it was announced in your blog).  Is it officially working now?  Right now I'm getting the 'Sorry, something went wrong' page.

Answer (score 1):

Requests is now available on mobile.  For more information see:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/

Answer (score 0):

set useragent as it is a desktop browser and makes facebook be happy